# How a container live in two networks can find each network's container with a same name

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

By "each network's container with a same name", I mean a scenario like this:

There are two networks, called one and two. In one, there is a container called server, and in two there is also a container called server. Now, if another container joins both one and two networks, how can it tell the two server containers apart?

This can be demonstrated with two docker-compose.yml files:

```
#server.yml

version: '3.7'
services:
  server:
    image: toolbelt/netcat
    entrypoint: nc -kl 1111
```

and

```
#client.yml

version: '3.7'
services:
  client:
    image: toolbelt/netcat
    networks:
      - one
      - two
    entrypoint:
      - sh
      - -c
      - echo abc | nc -q 1 server 1111

networks:
  one:
    external:
      name: one_default
  two:
    external:
      name: two_default
```

We can start the two servers with

```
docker-compose -p one -f server.yml up
docker-compose -p two -f server.yml up
```

and ask the client to connect with

```
docker-compose -p client -f client.yml up
```

And currently, only the server in network one echos `abc`, which means server in network two is shadowed.

I wonder how I can make the client be able to access both servers?

I'm aware of the network alias feature, where I can give each server a additional name in their own network, so if I make them unique, I can ask the client to access both. But in my real case, I have no permission to change server.yml.

Is it possible to somehow give servers alias names in client's docker-compose.yml file or are there some other ways to tell the two servers apart?

Comment: If the servers have the same name, I assume the same functionality, correct? If so, why not scale the server in e.g. network "one" to 2 replicas.

Comment: They have different functionalities. For example, two different db in different networks.

Comment: If the answer solved your question please accept it or provide additional information to further debug the issue at hand. If you have already found a solution please post it and accept it to share it with the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can connect to the distinct service via:

```
[container name].[project]_[network name]
```

For example

- your service is called "server"
- your project is called "one"
- your network in project "one" is called "default" (if none is specified default is used)

  `ping server.one_default`

Comment: This format doesn't work for me, but it inspired me to find that `two_server_1.two_default` resolves to server in network two. I guess the format  is `[container name].[network name]`?

Comment: Also, do you happen to know if this is documented anywhere?

Comment: If you can update the answer I'll accept it, thanks

Comment: Hi hgl, no I did not find any documentation in that regard, I just knew that it was possible in kubernetes / docker swarm, so the functionality needed to be there somewhere

Comment: I found the issue why it did not work for you and updated the answer once more. This should reflect the setup properly